# Printing images to scale (on multiple pages?)

Tags: windows, printing

I would like to find software to print images (svg, png, jpg, etc) to a scale I can set, with reasonable accuracy. If I could print on multiple page to tape together that would great. I'm wanting this for printing out templates for wood working.

The software must run on Windows 10, and its price should not exceed USD 50.

Comment: I would use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open source free program that works on Windows, OSX and Linux can be found on the [PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) web site.

I've used it in the past and the accuracy is quite good. You can adjust the overlap of the pages to allow for printer limitations, as well as configure for various standard paper sizes or use a custom setting.

I usually like to add a suitable image, but the SE image manager is having problems at this time. There are screenshots on the web site noted above.